# Force image size on WP custom field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, field

I want to force the images smaller to the width="128px" height="78px". They are being pulled in with Wordpress custom field.

**HTML**

```
     <?php $description = get_post_meta($post->ID, "project-thumb", $single = true);
if($description !== '') { echo $description; } ?>
```

**For working example:**
Rollover to the right of the screen, (need JS enabled)and notice the oversized image
http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/warface.co.uk/the-london-police

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the image by its URL and running it through the free timthumb script?

Tutorial: http://c.hadcoleman.com/2008/06/adding-timthumb-to-your-wordpress-theme/